# When the user clicks a button,then I have write code for hiding the current form and showing the next form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am doing Windows Forms Application. When the user clicks a button I am hiding the current page and navigating to another page.
// in the button click event

```
Vehicle_Registration ob = new Vehicle_Registration(this);
ob.Show();   
this.hide();
```

But the problem here is, in the Vehicle_registration Page, if the user clicks the Close Button in the Control Box then this page is closing, but the previous page(Main Page) is not in visible. I don't want to disable the Close Button. Where i Can write the code for visiability for the Main Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I get it right the way you are doing things, you pass `this` to the other form constructor so you have a reference to your first `Form` in there.

in the Form_Closing event of the second form just do `Parent.Show();` or anything similar using the form reference you got in the construction.

Answer (score 1):

```
Vehicle_Registration ob = new Vehicle_Registration(this); 
ob.FormClosed += ob_FormClosed;
ob.Show();    
this.hide(); 


void ob_FormClosed(Object sender, FormClosedEventArgs  e)
{
    // show current window here
}
```

Comment: It can't be FormClosed, the app will lose the focus when there's temporarily no window left that can get the focus.  Use FormClosing.

Answer (score 0):

Here it would help you a lot to abstract the notion of a Wizard into its own class. It would handle the show/hide of the different forms.

When you instantiate you would have to tell it the sequence of forms you will open. Every form that is subject to handling by the **WizardManager** should implement an interface that allows the Manager to know when the user presses next. You may also consider inheriting from a base form such that you can put common visual behaviour in one place.

```
public class WizardManager {
  public WizardManager AddStep<T>() where T : IWizardStep, new() {
    /* Add code */
    return this;
  }
  public void Start() {
    /* Show the first step */
  }
}
```

And you use it like

```
var mgr = new WizardManager();
mgr.Add<FirstStep>().Add<SecondStep>();
mgr.Start();
```

Here I am assuming that your forms have default constructor. Now you can place the show/hide code in the Manager and also the code that Alex provided to you. This is one of a number of ways to avoid code duplication as the show/hide/close handling is always the same.